does not provide an export named 'isEqual' | Angular
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';

onSave() {
    const isFormsEqual = isEqual(
      this.loyaltyRewardsFormFacade.currentRewardsState(),
      this.loyaltyRewardsFormFacade.transformFormData()
    );
    this.loyaltyRewardsFacade.onSave(this.loyaltyRewardsFormFacade, isFormsEqual);
  }

I'm encountering an error in my Angular project that blocks the project from loading.
I'm using an Nx monorepo with Angular's native module federation architecture. The project has a micro-frontend structure with two applications: a main Shell app and a remote app.
In one of the remote app's components, I needed Lodash's isEqual method. I installed the following packages: "@types/lodash": "^4.17.13" and "lodash": "^4.17.21". I imported isEqual from Lodash using import { isEqual } from 'lodash'; in the component and used the isEqual method. Initially, it worked fine, but now, as you can see, I'm getting an error that crashes the application, saying "does not provide an export named 'isEqual'," even though I'm importing it correctly.
Do you have any ideas about what might be causing this error? I've encountered similar errors a few times, especially when creating new effect and facade files. I'd use them initially without issues, but after pushing new changes, I’d get the "doesn't provide an export named" error, despite exporting and importing everything properly.
Please feel free to share your thoughts.
Thanks in advance!
error:
ERROR SyntaxError: The requested module 'blob:http://localhost:4200/e878b7c3-c148-4467-99c5-31459e1efa4c' does not provide an export named 'isEqual' (at routes-WEHG7TSS.js:1:78930)
I tried to remove node modules and run npm i

On the latest versions of Typescript (for me it was ~5.5.0).
You have to set the moduleResolution property to bundler, before it was node, for proper resolution of certain packages like lodash, keycloak-js, etc.
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler" /* <- changed here! */,
    ...

Bundler

'bundler' for use with bundlers. Like node16 and nodenext, this mode supports package.json "imports" and "exports", but unlike the Node.js resolution modes, bundler never requires file extensions on relative paths in imports.

Stackblitz Demo
Related Answer - keycloak-angular 26 is unable to find keycloak-js
